# Web API Routing error from RC to RTM with model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Upgrading an rc to rtm web api project

> Default parameter binding for simple type parameters is now [FromUri]: In previous releases of ASP.NET Web API the default parameter binding for simple type parameters used model binding. The default parameter binding for simple type parameters is now [FromUri].

I believe is the change that is causing me greif.

Well now I'm not so sure. [StrathWeb](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/asp-net-web-api-is-released-whats-new-in-web-api-rtm-and-how-to-use-it/) seems to make me thing it should just work as is.

Given this endpoint

```
   [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Method(string a, string b)
    {
     ...
    }
```

I generate a url on the client using

```
@Url.RouteUrl("route", new { httproute = "", controller = "Controller", version = "1" })">
```

to get it to generate the url for this route.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "route",
routeTemplate: "api/v{version}/{controller}/Method",
defaults: new
{
    action = "Method",
    controller = "Controller",
    version = "1"
});
```

It creates the url fine. The urls looks like

```
.../api/v1/Controller/Method?optional=z
.../api/v1/Controller/Method?a=x&b=y&optional=z
```

It throws a 404 when requested. If I remove the parameters a and b in the api controller then it enters the method just fine.

What is the correct way to make these bind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you need 'a' and 'b' to be optional, then you would need to make them optional parameters:

public HttpResponseMessage Method(string a **= null**, string b **= null**)

Comment: I tried this before and it didn't work. I must have screwed something up in between since that is working now.

Comment: In the routing you can set a and b to be `UrlParameter.Optional` in the defaults section. I don't think you need to do `string a = null` in the method as `string` is a nullable type by default?

Comment: You could do UrlParameter.Optional 'if' the parameters come from the route. if they are coming from querystring we need to say " string a = null " even though its a nullable type...this is a change from RC behavior..